# CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match '*, *'

Tags: .htaccess, cors

When fetching a resource from a server with Firefox, I get this error message:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource
> Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘*, *’

What does `'*, *'` mean? Where did this value come from? I use that value nowhere! My `.htaccess` file contains the following, which I believe should be sufficient to allow all origins:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Answer (score 3):

The most simple explanation is that the response received by the browser contains two `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers:

```http
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

As part of [the CORS check](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-check), the browser effectively [joins the values of multiple `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers into one](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-header-list-get) using the character sequence `,`  as separator. In your specific case, it's as if your browser received a response containing the following header:

```http
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, *
```

However, a value of `*, *` never denotes all origins; only [the wildcard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-new-header-syntax), composed of a single `*` character, can denote all origins.

You need to find out why the response contains multiple `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers and make sure it contains at most one. Most likely, your CORS middleware is adding one, and your Web server or some reverse proxy is adding another.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that was exactly the problem. But in my defense the two headers were set at different locations, one in htaccess and one in an OPTIONS response.