# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed

Tags: cors

I'm getting this error on this script

```
let path = "https://one-station.it/script/onair.php";

$.getJSON(path, function(result) {

    alert(result);

});
```

I have this htaccess in the server:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Accept application/json API
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=API
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT" env=API
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization" env=API

    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

I only get this error with getJSON if I do it with $.GET or $.POST it works fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match '\*, \*'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72200848/cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-does-not-match)

Comment: Did you notice you have both `Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=API` and `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`?