CORS ERROR: Something went wrong. Please try again later
I'm having the following issue when trying to connect to Sagemaker Studio Lab.
I was using the platform normally during the last 2 weeks, however, in the past days I have experience this error regularly, but today it won't let me in.
This is what I found out through the Inspector console:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://gateway.prod.us-east-2.studiolab.sagemaker.aws/v1/signin. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘https://studiolab.sagemaker.aws, *’).
I will appreciate your help to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.
I tried using different browsers and wifi networks, without any success.

Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72200848/cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-does-not-match/72202727#72202727

Same issues are reported on GitHub forum side as well.
https://github.com/aws/studio-lab-examples/issues/254
https://github.com/aws/studio-lab-examples/issues/255
Investigation is in-progress. Please watch them.

This issue was reported also on SageMaker's GitHub forum, and there was a response that the there was a deployment to solve this issue:
https://github.com/aws/studio-lab-examples/issues/254#issuecomment-2067865733
